# How to set asset images in container background image with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I know how to set image file in container.
However when I try to set background of Container in ListView, the images can not shown up.

Of course, I wrote these image files in `pubspec.yaml`.

```
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/IMG_01.JPG'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/IMG_02.JPG'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Give me advice.
Thank you.

Comment: what if you give any fixed size to both `Container`s? try for testing  `width: 100, height: 100`

Comment: I figured out. The container is supposed to be adjusted to widgets inside.
That is why nothing is shown up.
I set height property to container.

Comment: Yes, Thank you for your advice.